# laravel one to many(select all rows from second table)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to select all services rows from servs table 
_____ i have two tables `users` with model(User) ..... and `servs` with model(servs) ... . uwant to select all rows from servs when it auth User
How can i do that ???

```
public function postserv(){
        $serv   =   User::find(Auth::user()->id)->servs;
        $serv   =   $serv->first();
        return $serv->serv_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the model name, but it should be something like `Serv::all()`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague and it's hard to determine what's going on in your project but I'll give it a shot.

If you want to select all rows of a model use the following:
`Services::all()`

Whilst that is what you're explicitly asking for, your question seems to pertain to a relationship where you select all services for a user.
`User::find(Auth::user()->id)->servs()->get();`

This will return all services that are joined to the authorised user, on the note of naming conventions you should make your relations more readable.
Also note that you must have your relationships set up in your Eloquent models else the above code would fail.

In future try to add a little more detail for your questions, there is more information about relationships in the Eloquent ORM on the Laravel website.

Comment: Actually if he did it the right way then $serv already contains all of the services. It is a big if but in that case it might be right.

Comment: i have two tables `users` with model(User) ..... and `servs` with model(servs) ... . uwant to select all rows from servs when it auth User

Comment: If you just want to select all the services and absolutely nothing else then using the `servs::all()` method will get all of them as every one including myself has said before.

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelName::all();
```

Returns all rows from a model/table.